# Why does clearing a passed table not work inside the function's scope?

Tags: function, lua, scope, lua-table

Clearing a table like so causes expected behavior:

```
table1 = { "a" }
table1 = {}
print(unpack(table1))        -- results in printing a blank line
```

But if you do the same thing inside a function, it doesn't take:

```
table1 = { "a" }

function cleartest (x)
    x = {}
    print(unpack(x))
end

cleartest(table1)            -- results in printing a blank line
print(unpack(table1))        -- results in "a"
```

What causes this behavior?

Edit:  To clarify how passing tables in Lua works.  x is not a local "copy" of table1, since it is a "value is reference" type, it is actually a reference to the actual table.  For example:

```
table1 = { "a" }

function xisref (x)
    x[2] = "b"
end

xisref(table1)
print(unpack(table1))         -- results in printing "a    b" thus x is a reference to the actual table
```

Comment: Your edit shows that you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about how values and variables work in Lua.

Comment: please let me know specifically where my example is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you cannot actually clear the value of a table - only a name.

If you do

```
table1 = { "a" }
table1 = {}
```

You don't set `{ "a" }` to `{}`, but you set `table1` to `{}` replacing the previous value. That value is now inaccessible and will eventually be cleared by the garbage collector.

When you call `cleartest`, then `x` will **also** point to the same value `{ "a" }` as `table1`, but `x` is a different (local) name for it. By doing `x = {}` you simply make `x` point to a new and empty table, but that changes nothing about `table1` which still points to `{ "a" }`.

Responding to your edit:

Yes `x` is a reference to the same value as `table1`. **But** `x` is still just a local name that happens to point to that value. The moment you assign something to `x`, the local variable `x` points to something new, without affecting the value it had previously pointed to.

Try this (anywhere, globally, locally, doesn't matter):

```
test1 = { "a" }
test2 = test1
-- printing them now gives the same table
test1 = 5
-- printing test1 gives 5; printing test2 still gives the table
```

Assigning something new to `test2` and printing `test1` would yield the same result.

Comment: I understand.  It was all a misconception about how assignment works.  Such a simple thing.  Thanks so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

You're not clearing the table. You're creating a new table and assigning it to the variable.

In the first case, you're overwriting the `table1` variable, so the later reference gets your new empty table.

In the second case, you're overwriting the `x` variable, which is local to the function, so the later reference to `table1` is unaffected. Note that if you had said `table1 = {}` in your `cleartest()` function it would have behaved like the first case.

If you truly want to clear the existing table, such that other references to the same table see the cleared state, you need to write something like

```
for k in pairs(x) do
    rawset(x, k, nil)
end
```

Comment: The x variable is not local to the function, it's a reference to the actual table.  For instance x[2] = "b" inside the function would append table1 outside the function's scope.

Comment: @RossCharette: You're wrong. `x` *is* local to the function. But it's *also* a reference to the actual table. But that doesn't change the fact that assignments to `x` won't actually affect the original table.

Comment: @RossCharette: If I had the code `local a = { "a" }; local b = a; b = {}; print(unpack(a))`, what do you think will happen? Your question implies you believe it will print nothing, but in fact it will print `a`, because the assignment to `b` did not actually change `a`.

Comment: assignments to x certainly do change the original table, see my edit in the original question above and test it yourself.

Comment: @RossCharette no. `x[2] = "b"` is **not** an assignment to `x`. `x` first gets evaluated as a name that points to your value `{ "a" }` (which is the same value that `table1` points to). Then `[2] = "b"` is an assignment that happens on this value. Try `x = {"b"}` inside the function: it won't change `table1`, because this **is** an assignment to `x`. If you don't believe Kevin or me, have a read in the reference manual. I've updated my answer with another clarifying example.